# How can I merge multiple columns that have the same name in a dataframe while avoiding duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am very new to python and pandas. I have a dataframe with several columns that have the same name. Each column contains a string or NaN. I want to merge the columns with the same name and avoid any duplicates.

Ideally I would like to get:

df1:

```
      Description
    0 string
    1 dr. A
    2 Theme 
    3 open
```

from the input dataframe below:

df1:

```
      Description Description Description Description
    0 string      NaN          string     NaN
    1 dr. A       dr. A        NaN        NaN
    2 Theme       Theme        Theme      Theme 
    3 NaN         NaN          open       open
```

Comment: Please provide another clearer example.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).first()`

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the green tick to the comment but @Erfan answer worked great

Comment: Added it as answer, you can accept that one if you want :) @Kia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use backfill (`bfill`) and `iloc` here:

```
df1.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```